# Use WHERE ... IN with multiple columns selection

Tags: sqlite

I want to update the `data` column in tbl1 when both `key1` and `key2` are listed in the results of another query:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(
  "key1" INT,
  "key2" INT,
  "data" VARCHAR(20)
);

UPDATE tbl1 set data="test 123"
WHERE
   (key1, key2)
IN
   (SELECT key1, key2 from tbl2 where user='123')
```

The `SELECT key1, key2 from tbl2 where user='123'` **alone** returns something like:

```
|key1|key2|
|----|----|
| 2  | 5  |
|----|----|
| 9  | 4  |
|----|----|
| 1  | 12 |
|----|----|
```

So the `UPDATE` would have to affect `tbl1` only the rows where `key1` and `key2` are listed in the `SELECT` rows.

What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the keys in separate conditions and using AND.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(
  "key1" INT,
  "key2" INT,
  "data" VARCHAR(20)
);

UPDATE tbl1 set data="test 123"
WHERE
   (key1 IN (SELECT key1 from tbl2 where user='123'))
   AND (key2 IN (SELECT key2 FROM tbl2 WHERE user='123));
```

This would mean running the SELECT query twice (unless the optimizer is clever); I don't think there is a way to avoid that, but would be glad to be proved wrong.

Comment: I'll have to agree with you. There will be 2 `SELECT` then.

Comment: I've tried your answer but the statement is affecting rows that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Not a beautiful one but it is a solution.

```
UPDATE tbl1 set data = "test 123"

where 
(
   (key1 || "," || key2)

   IN

   (select (key1 || "," || key2) from tbl2 where user='123' ) 

)
```